# I want to drag and drop each of my new dynamic table cell content multiple time using clone? how can i change the cell back ground colour?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, d3.js

I want to drag and drop each of my new dynamic table cell content multiple time using clone? how can i change the cell back ground color? dropping area will be another div. actually i want to generate dynamic table with above functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<input type="button" value="Generate Table()"onclick="GenerateTable()" />
<hr />
<div id="dvTable">
</div>
<script>
function GenerateTable() {

var customers = new Array();
customers.push(["Customer Id", "Name", "Country"]);
customers.push([1, "John Hammond", "United States"]);
customers.push([2, "Mudassar Khan", "India"]);
customers.push([3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France"]);
customers.push([5, "Robert Schidner", "Russia"]);
customers.push([4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia"]);
//Create a HTML Table element.
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
table.border = "1";

var columnCount = customers[0].length;

var row = table.insertRow(-1);
for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
    headerCell.innerHTML = customers[0][i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
}

for (var i = 1; i < customers.length; i++) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerHTML = customers[i][j];
    }
}

var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
dvTable.innerHTML = "";
dvTable.appendChild(table);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```